# How to define tuples with optional elements?

Tags: algorithms

I want to formalize an algorithm using mathematical definitions but the problem is that many of my object oriented constructs contain optional elements. For example, a house $h = (s,n,m)$ always has a street $s$ and a house number $n$ but not always has a mailbox $m$. In programming languages, $m$ could be an empty optional or a null value, but I did not find a mathematical equivalent to this concept. Using a set seems misleading here, as I am sure it will never have more than one element in it, but is it my only option or is there a better suited formalism?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Choose $h$ from 
$$
H = S \times N \times (M \cup \{ \epsilon, \text{null} \})
$$
where $S$ is the set of streets, $N$ the set of house numbers, $M$ the set of mailboxes, $\epsilon$ is an empty optional (whatever that is) and $\text{null}$ is your null value, the latter both distinct from all elements in $M$.

Or define
$$
H = S \times N \cup S \times N \times M 
$$